# android studio calculator app

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been working on a calculator app, the code is running bar the equal button which is not showing any results. I am not sure where I have gone wrong with the code.my calculator is a simple one which is only required to add and subtract.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2.16"
    android:id="@+id/linear1">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="0"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="30pt"
        android:id="@+id/noOne"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linear2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#3090C7"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#41A317"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/buttonplus"/>

  </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linear3">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/button4"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/button5"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/buttonminus"/>

   </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linear4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/button7"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/button8"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/buttondecimal"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linear5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/button0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.88"
        android:text="="
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/buttonequal"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:text="AC"
        android:textSize="25pt"
        android:id="@+id/buttonAC"/>

  </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18pt"
        android:id="@+id/results"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
package example.uuj.studentbudget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText noOne;
Button buttonplus, buttonminus, buttondecimal, buttonequal, buttonAC;
Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7,               
button8, button9, button0;
TextView results;
Double double1;
Double double2;
Boolean plus, minus;
int val1, val2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //declaring edit text

    noOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noOne);

    //declaring all button number
    button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);

    //declaring all button operations
    buttonplus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonplus);
    buttonminus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonminus);
    buttondecimal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondecimal);
    buttonequal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonequal);
    buttonAC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAC);

    results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.results);


    //set up all event handlers for numbered buttons

    //Button0

    button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                       //interface

                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       TextView results = (TextView)  
 findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                       results.append("0");
                                   }
                               }
    );

    //Button1
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                       //interface
                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       TextView results = (TextView) 
 findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                       results.append("1");
                                   }
                               }
    );

    //Button2
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                       //interface

                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       TextView results = (TextView) 

 findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                       results.append("2");
                                   }
                               }
    );

    //Button3
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                       //interface

                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       TextView results = (TextView) 
  findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                       results.append("3");
                                   }
                               }
    );

    //Button4
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                       //interface

                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       TextView results = (TextView) 
  findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                       results.append("4");
                                   }
                               }
    );

    //Button5
    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                       //interface

                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       TextView results = (TextView)  
 findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                       results.append("5");
                                   }
                               }
    );
    //Button6
    button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                       //interface

                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       TextView results = (TextView) 
  findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                       results.append("6");
                                   }
                               }
    );

    //Button7
    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                       //interface

                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       TextView results = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                       results.append("7");
                                   }
                               }
    );

    //Button8
    button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                       //interface

                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       TextView results = (TextView) 
  findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                       results.append("8");
                                   }
                               }
    );

    //Button9
    button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                       //interface

                               {
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       TextView results = (TextView) 
 findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                       results.append("9");
                                   }
                               }
    );

    //Button to clear all data from the screen
    buttonAC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                        //interface

                                {
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        TextView results = (TextView) 
   findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                        results.setText("");
                                    }
                                }
    );

    //Buttondecimal
    buttondecimal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                             //interface

                                     {
                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                             TextView results = (TextView) 
  findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                             results.append(".");
                                         }
                                     }
    );

    //plus button
    buttonplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            val1 = Integer.parseInt(noOne.getText() + "");
            plus = true;
            noOne.setText(null);
        }
    });

    //minus button
    buttonminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            val1 = Integer.parseInt(noOne.getText() + "");
            minus = true;
            noOne.setText(null);
        }
    });

    buttonequal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            val2 = Integer.parseInt(noOne.getText() + "");

            if (plus == true) {
                noOne.setText(val1 + val2 + "");
                plus = false;
            }
            if (minus == true) {
                noOne.setText(val1 + val2 + "");
                minus = false;
            }
        }

    });
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "running bar the equal button"

Comment: The text will appear on the screen when a numbered button is selected  but when I click on the equal button, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I would like to first point out some of the mistakes you have done.***

- You have given a decimal button but it is never handled inside program. this will make your app crash.
- You have to improve on better overall design. after one operation you don't clear the edittext.

***and now answer to your question -***

> ..the equal button which is not showing any results..

- You have problem in every button `onClickListener()` . the noOne is a `EditText` but you are casting it as a `TextView`. change it in every `setOnClickListener` -

  ```
  button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                     //interface

                             {
                                 public void onClick(View v) {
                                     EditText results = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noOne);
                                     results.append("0");
                                 }
                             }
  );
  ```
- The variable `plus` and `minus` are `boolean` not `Boolean` . so do this -

  ```
  boolean plus, minus;
  ```

*Now your code will run fine for the equal buttton carsh problem . but i have to say this " this program still needs improvement".*

Please do accept this answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment at the moment, but is it possible that you're hitting both Add and Minus at the same time.  The way they are being set isn't mutually exclusive so it is possible that they are both passing and the noOne is being updated to the original val2 since you're adding then subtracting the same val1 number?

You may want to have an Operation variable that is set to either Operation.PLUS or Operation.MINUS and then in your equals handler switch the value so that you're only doing one operation at a time.  If you add in other operations after, you won't run into that problem if someone hits a number both + and - before hitting equal.

Answer (score 0):

While declaring the Boolean plus and minus, initialize them to false because it'll give a null pointer exception in the **'buttonequal'** onClickListener.

```
Boolean plus = false, minus = false;
```

There is one more problem in this code, you have added the numbers both the times, as in your 'minus' logic your are adding the numbers instead of subtracting them.

```
buttonequal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            val2 = Integer.parseInt(noOne.getText() + "");

            if (plus == true) {
                noOne.setText(val1 + val2 + "");
                plus = false;
            }
            if (minus == true) {
                //noOne.setText(val1 + val2 + ""); changed this to minus
                noOne.setText(val1 - val2 + "");
                minus = false;
            }
        }

    });
```

After making this changes your code should work fine.